# 2 dropdown menus to open URLs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 separate dropdowns. 
I want to use JavaScript to change the URL upon dropdown selection.
It almost works as I'm passing a value but I'm still getting an 'undefined' in the URL window.
The code is bellow:

**JavaScript:**

```
 function callDDfunction(val) {
       alert("The new value is: " + val);
        if (this.selectedIndex!==0) {
            window.location.href = this.value;
        }

       };
```

**HTML:**

```
<select onchange="callDDfunction(this.value)">
                      <option value="">Site Navigation:</option> 
                      <option value="index.php">Home</option>
                      <option value="register.php">Sign Up</option>
</select> 

<select onchange="callDDfunction(this.value)">
                      <option value="">Seasons Archive:</option> 
                      <option value="/seasons/nba/2012-13/">Season 1: NBA 2012-2013</option>
                      <option value="/seasons/nba/2013-14/">Season 2: NBA 2013-2014</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

In your code `this` refers to the `window` object which doesn't have `value` property. You are passing the value to your function, `val` argument is the current value, simply use it:

```
window.location.href = val;
```

If you want to have access to the select element for checking the `selectedIndex` property, pass the element itself instead of it's value:

```
<select onchange="callDDfunction(this)">
```

Then your function's body will be:

```
function callDDfunction(elem) {
    alert("The new value is: " + elem.value);
    if (elem.selectedIndex !== 0) {
        window.location.href = elem.value;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

use `this.val()` instead of `this.value`